Add class to one fancybox thumb
There is a fancybox gallery with thumbs. There are images and one video in the gallery. Tell please, how can I add a class for thumb that opens the video? FancyBox v3.5.7. Here is code:
<div class="fancybox-thumbs__list">
    <a href="javascript:;" tabindex="0" data-index="0" style="background-image:url(/tl_hospital_43-1.jpg)" class="fancybox-thumbs-active"></a>
    <a href="javascript:;" tabindex="0" data-index="1" style="background-image:url(/tl_hospital_43-1.jpg)"></a>
    <a href="javascript:;" tabindex="0" data-index="2" style="background-image:url(/tl_hospital_43-1.jpg)"></a>
    <a href="javascript:;" tabindex="0" data-index="3" style="background-image:url(/tl_hospital_43-1.jpg)"></a>
    <a href="javascript:;" tabindex="0" data-index="4" style="background-image:url(/tl_hospital_43-1.jpg)"></a>
    <a href="javascript:;" tabindex="0" data-index="5" style="background-image:url(/tl_CMG_270_b_001.jpg)">     
    </a>
</div>

Thanx in advance!!!!
